# How to add “Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart” to only certain items

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, ce-1.9.0.1, stores, shopping

I know I can set a maximum number of items that can be in the shopping cart at one time... But is there a way to selectively set what is limited?

For example...
I want customers to be able to order as many of the "core product" as they want, but I would like to limit the amount of samples one can purchase per order.

So, is there a way to make it so that the limitation is not global but is isolated to a specific category?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried changing the settings in the inventory tab for the specific product?

```
Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
```

Uncheck "Use config settings" and add the amount in the text field.

Give that a try first...